# Text behind opaque header background

Tags: html, css

I would like to figure out how to scroll my text into my header with an opaque background so you can see the text its just very blurry. How I would like this to look is for text to scroll behind the header but still show up. Something that looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gro6e22p/) but instead of the text being completely gone, I would like it to be behind an opaque background. I have tried using `opacity`, but haven't had any luck with that. There are a few other questions like this on this website, but none seem to answer this question. I have also looked into things like some custom js frameworks, but haven't been able to find anything that would work.

To summarize what I'm ask is how would I have text that scrolls though my header but with an opacity on the header so that the text is visible, but not readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the header background to rgba(), like this:

```
header{
    background : rgba(255,255,255,0.5);     /* white background with 50% opacity */
}
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/gro6e22p/1/

Comment: I would up vote this answer, but I only have a 5 rep, since I just started using stackoverflow.